# Int in a For loop inside future not incrementing Flutter/Firestore

Tags: flutter, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore, future

I'm trying to set many Firestore documents with a for loop, with an incrementing variable, but this one is not incrementing like it does...
Here is the code

```
int debutRdv = 0;

).then((valueEnregistrement) => {
 for(PrestationSelected prestaSelect in prestaSelected){
  rdvService.createRdv(
   cli: cli, 
   debutRdv: debutRdv, 
   heureCreneau: heureCreneau, 
   prestaSelect: prestaSelect, 
   valueEnregistrement: valueEnregistrement
  )
  .then((valueRdv) => {
   for (int i = 0; i < prestaSelect.duree; i += 15){
    rdvService.createCreneau(
     debutRdv: debutRdv, 
     heureCreneau: heureCreneau, 
     i: i, 
     prestaSelect: prestaSelect, 
     valueRdv: valueRdv
    )
   },
   debutRdv = debutRdv += prestaSelect.duree
   })
  },
```

The fact is the variable debutRdv is not incrementing like i want. It increment correctly in the second loop (createCreneau) but not in the first loop (createRdv). It's like the function createRdv was running as many time as my list prestaSelected's length before running the "then"...
I really don't understand what's happenning.

For example result should be :

```
*debutRdv Rdv1 = 0  
debutRdv Rdv1Creneau 1 = 0  
debutRdv Rdv1Creneau 2 = 0  
debutRdv Rdv2 = 30  
debutRdv Rdv2Creneau 1 = 30  
debutRdv Rdv2Creneau 2 = 30*
```

but it is:

```
*debutRdv Rdv1 = 0  
debutRdv Rdv1Creneau 1 = 0  
debutRdv Rdv1Creneau 2 = 0  
debutRdv Rdv2 = 0  
debutRdv Rdv2Creneau 1 = 30  
debutRdv Rdv2Creneau 2 = 30*
```

Plz help.

Comment: Just a suggestion: I find async/await syntax easier to debug and read than the 'then' syntax. I'm suggesting this change because you have nested Futures with For loops and that's going to get complicated fast.

Answer (score 1):

**The issue:** Your first for-in statement isn't going to wait for rdvService.createRdv().then() to finish before moving to the next item, which results in nondeterminant (unpredictable) execution order of your functions.

I don't know how to do what you're trying to do using then() for futures- I'm not sure it's actually possible. You can do it with for or for-in using async/await instead of then(). (I've learned when I need deterministic iterators in Dart to use regular for loops like your second loop.) If you want to try async/await, there's an [article here](https://dev.to/uchennaemeruche/iterating-asynchronous-operations-in-dart-using-foreach-and-for-in-loop-1n4f) that covers async programming and for-in and forEach loops.